# Do UPDATE in the first place and then INSERT for new data (reports) into mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I get a report in a tab delimited file which stores some SKUs and the current quantities of them.
Which means most of the time the inventory is the same and we just have to update the quantities.
But it can happen, that a new SKU is in the list which we have to insert instead of updating.

We are using an INNODB table for storing those SKUs. At the moment we just cut the file by tabs and line breaks and make an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query which is quite inefficient, because `INSERT` is expensive at INNODB, right? Also tricky because when a list with a lot of SKUs coming in > 20k it just take some minutes.

So my resolution for now is to just make a `LOAD DATA INFILE` into an tmp table and afterwards do the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, which should be faster i think.

Also is there another solution which does a simple `UPDATE` in the first place and only if there are some left, it performs and `INSERT`? This would be perfect, but yet i could not find anything about it. Is there a way to delete rows which returned an `update: 1`?

Comment: `when a list with a lot of SKUs coming in > 20k it just take some minutes` - something is wrong with your system. This should take seconds at the most.

Comment: Yeah I now. It is crappy how it gets done at the moment. That's why we wanna change but we wanna make it good this time. So do you have any suggestions for us?

Comment: Are you batching the inputs or doing them one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the CSV file by the PRIMARY KEY of the table.
2. LOAD DATA INFILE into a separate table (as you said)
3. INSERT INTO real_table SELECT * FROM tmp_table ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... -- Note: This is a single INSERT.

Caveat:  This may block the table from other uses during step 3.  A solution:  Break the CSV into 1000-row chunks.  COMMIT after each chunk.